# Angular6 Resolver not working, resolver not sending data to the component

Tags: angular, angular6, resolver, angular-resolver

I've got a [project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebslwf) in Angular6, and I'm using a resolver to fetch data before component gets loaded but it's not working properly. The resolver is being called but I'm not getting any data in the component.

Here the stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebslwf

Comment: Is the data you want to fetch is from an API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just played with your blitz.

It is because your app.component.html is not using a `<router-outlet>`

Try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reading-data-from-resolver?file=src/app/hello.component.ts